# IIS 6 & 7 - change the default message that is displayed when an application pool is stopped

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7, iis-6

i would like to change the default message that is displayed when an application pool is stopped in IIS 6, currently the default message is "**Service Unavailable**". i would like to change it to "**The Web Application is currently being upgraded**" and also include an image.

please will someone kindly assist with this?

thanks,

best
muzi

Comment: Yo can see more related answers here: http://serverfault.com/questions/483145/how-to-add-a-site-wide-downtime-error-message-in-iis-with-a-custom-503-error-co

Answer (score 4, accepted):

503 Error comes from HTTP.SYS so you cannot change it from IIS.

If you are stopping the application pool during update of your ASP.NET website, best way would be to add a file called **App_Offline.htm** in the root folder with whatever you want to show users when application is offline.

ASP.NET runtime would redirect requests to this file if it's found in the website folder.
So once you are done, you can just rename this file.

This link also might help since it's related.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx

Comment: thanks for kindly getting back to me. The "App_Offline.htm" is perfect because it doesn't require me to physically stop the application pool via IIS in order to stop my ASP.NET web app. Thanks this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [you can't change the HTTP 503 Error page displayed when the AppPool is stopped.](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx?mfr=true)

> The following errors are not customizable: 400, 403.9, 411, 414, 500, 500.11, 500.14, 500.15, 501, **503**, and 505.

(emphasis added)

Comment: Oh i see, thanks for kindly getting back to me. As Sukesh suggested the "App_Offline.htm" is what i was looking for. thanks again